# How to create a queue of dictionaries per customer?

Tags: python, dictionary, queue

I am a beginner at python. We have an assignment that is requiring us to create a queue of dictionaries. I am unsure how to do this inside of a list. Here is my code (btw this is play code, not used functionally) My main goal is to have a better understanding of this. Code:

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        
    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.size() == 0:
            return None
        return self.items.pop(0)

    def show_queue(self):
        print(self.items)  


# CODE CHALLENGE
class IceCreamShop:
    order = {
        "customer" : "",
        "flavor" : "",
        "scoops" : "",
    }
    def __init__(self, flavors):
        self.flavors = flavors
        order = Queue()
        
        
    def take_order(self, customer, flavor, scoops):
        if flavor in self.flavors and scoops in range(1, 4):
            for orders in self.order:
                self.order["customer"] = customer
                self.order["flavor"] = flavor
                self.order["scoops"] = scoops
                print("Order Created!")
                print(self.order)
                return self.order         
        else:
            print("Sorry, we don't have that flavor.\n Pick another flavor or less scoops.")
            
            
    def show_all_orders(self):
        for orders in self.order.values():
            print(self.order)
            
    def next_order(self):
        # show next order in queue
        print("Next Order...")
           
            
shop = IceCreamShop(["rocky road", "mint chip", "pistachio"])
shop.take_order("Zachary", "pistachio", 3)
shop.take_order("Marcy", "mint chip", 1)
shop.take_order("Leopold", "vanilla", 2)
shop.take_order("Bruce", "rocky road", 0)
shop.show_all_orders()
shop.next_order()
shop.show_all_orders()
```

What I don't understand is,

1. How do I save a dictionary for each customer inside of a queue?
2. How would I "dequeue" and "enqueue" the dictionary per customer
3. In the "take_orders" function, it does return 2 different customers, Zach and Marcy
4. But in the "show_all_orders" function, it is only printing out Marcy? Why is this?

**EDIT:
I used the solution given below, and used a for loop to print out the values in a slightly different way. I am just sharing here in case someone else needs..**

```html
# CODE CHALLENGE
class IceCreamShop:
    def __init__(self, flavors):
        self.flavors = flavors
        self.orders = Queue()
        
        
    def take_order(self, customer, flavor, scoops):
        if flavor in self.flavors and scoops in range(1, 4):
                order = dict()
                order["customer"] = customer
                order["flavor"] = flavor
                order["scoops"] = scoops
                self.orders.enqueue(order)
                print("Order Created!")
      
        else:
            print("\nSorry, we don't have that flavor.\nPick another flavor or less scoops.\n")
            
            
    def show_all_orders(self):
        print("\nAll Pending Ice Cream Orders:")
        for orders in self.orders.items:
            print(("Customer: " + orders["customer"]), ("-- Flavor: " + orders["flavor"]), ("-- Scoops:" + str(orders["scoops"])))


            
    def next_order(self):
        print("\nNext Order Up!")
        order = self.orders.dequeue()
        print(("Customer: " + order["customer"]), ("-- Flavor: " + order["flavor"]), ("-- Scoops:" + str(order["scoops"])))
                 
shop = IceCreamShop(["rocky road", "mint chip", "pistachio"])
shop.take_order("Zachary", "pistachio", 3)
shop.take_order("Marcy", "mint chip", 1)
shop.take_order("Leopold", "vanilla", 2)
shop.take_order("Bruce", "rocky road", 0)
shop.show_all_orders()
shop.next_order()
shop.show_all_orders()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. let's create queue in `__init__` of `IceCreamShop` class to store orders

   ```
   self.orders = Queue()
   ```
2. You don't need to have an `order` blank template in `IceCreamShop` class. Because you can create local variable `order` in function `take_order` and then add this `order` to queue `self.orders`

   ```
   def take_order(self, customer, flavor, scoops):
       if flavor in self.flavors and scoops in range(1, 4):
           order = dict()
           order["customer"] = customer
           order["flavor"] = flavor
           order["scoops"] = scoops
           self.orders.enqueue(order)

           print("Order Created!")
           print(order)
           # return self.order
       else:
           print("Sorry, we don't have that flavor.\n Pick another flavor or less scoops.")
   ```
3. Let's change function `show_all_orders`

   ```
   def show_all_orders(self):
       self.orders.show_queue()
   ```
4. Here we can give next order to customer and remove from queue

   ```
   def next_order(self):
       # show next order in queue
       print("Next Order...")
       return self.orders.dequeue()
   ```

Comment: This is perfect, I totally understand how this works. Thank you so much.